# jQuery / Ajax search by particular field

Tags: jquery, ajax, search, field, quick-search

I have it all setup and working fine - what id like to do is have it only search by one particular field in a table (td with class of test).

Im using 
`$('input#SearchBox').quicksearch('table#tablesorter-demo tbody tr');`

which searches all the fields in the table, I have tried:

$('input#SearchBox').quicksearch('table#tablesorter-demo tbody tr td.test');

but this just stops the whole search from working, ideas appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input#SearchBox').quicksearch('table#tablesorter-demo tbody tr', {'selector': 'td.test'})
```

[Working JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/3nuZD/)

Comment: this may be on the right track - when using the search all the fields disappear (the ones not containing the keyword should be the only ones to disappear). However previous tries nothing at all happened, just left all fields showing...

Comment: @Sean Is there definitely some cells with the class of test that contain matching data?

Comment: @Sean I have added a working jsfiddle example using that selector.

Comment: @InfernalBadger - yes there is definetly a cell with matching data of that class. However your jsfiddle examp[le does nothing for me either...im wondering if its to do with me using IE9...shal ltry another browser when i get a chance. Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: @Sean That could be the problem. I have noticed quite a few problems with IE9 and JS. Haven't got it installed on this machine though so can't check.

Comment: @InfernalBadger - Just checked in Firefox too and unfortunately still is not working..

Comment: @Sean My jsfiddle example works for me in firefox. As you type in the box it will grey out rows where the ID doesn't match (as that is the one i've added the test class to).

Answer (score 0):

Try being less specific in your criteria:

```
$('input#SearchBox').quicksearch('.test');
```

Comment: unfortunately the same problem - stops working all together, thanks though.